# how to filter by hiding/showing divs with dynamic attributes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have checkboxes x, y, z and `<div>` elements with corresponding `id` attributes.

I have products in groups of x, y, z and the groups have classes. But the `clearfix` class is for all the products in different locations (because I loop through products) so I should recognize the difference with id and other things.

If a checkbox has been checked it should show the related div (if `x`, show `<div id='x'>`). If not it should not show them. If x, and y are checked, show x, y and hide z.

So it should work with multiple ones. Here are my divs and styles of clearfix that caused the problem:

```css
.clearfix:after { 
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix { 
    zoom: 1; 
    display: block;
}
.clearfix:after{
    display: block; 
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="reltitles" id="<?php echo $array[$key][0]; ?>" style="<?php if($array[$key][1]==0){?> display:none;<?php }else {?>display:block;<?php }?>">
    <font class="resultHeader">
         (<?php echo $array[$key][1];?>) <?php  echo $array[$key][0]; ?>
    </font> 
</div>
<div class="clearfix" value="<?php echo $array[$key][0];?>" name="<?php echo $array[$key][0];?>" id="<?php echo $array[$key][0];?>">
    <?php //code for showing items
```

Following are the scripts that failed to hide the clear fix:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var variable = $(this);
        $(".clearfix").each(function () {
            if( $(this).attr("value") != variable.val() ) {
                var id = $(this).attr("value");
                var x = document.getElementById(id);
                if ( x.style.display == "block" ) { 
                    x.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    x.style.display = "block";
                }
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The first time it should show all of the items and then if user ties to filter them start the operation.

Comment: it would be much easier to fix the js if you just post the rendered html (without php). A http://jsfiddle.net would be nice too

Comment: updated if you want to consider

Comment: @Nickparsa Can you share your generated HTML? The code you provided here doesn't include any checkboxes, or how the relationship between them and the `<div>` elements in the DOM.

Comment: I solved my problem you can see my answer what do you mean by that? you want me to show the page source ?

Comment: @Nickparsa When the browser loads this page, all of the PHP has been processed, leaving only HTML tags/attributes. I would like to see your remaining HTML. I suspect we could come up with a better approach than what you posted here as your answer

Comment: @JonathanSampson please tell me where exactly I should search in the page source to show it to you it is a long long page

Comment: @Nickparsa In your question you said "Suppose I have checkboxes x, y, z and <div> elements with corresponding id attributes," so I would like to see the HTML for these checkboxes, and the associated div elements.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I am busy but I tried to show you partially in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/neginparsa/vLdGT/1/

Comment: @Nickparsa Does http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dXKLL/6/ not give the effect you're looking for?

Comment: @JonathanSampson yeah it is reasonable,but I already deployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I figured it out, I loop through all checkboxes and all divs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
            $(".clearfix").each(function(){
                var clear=$(this);
             $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                 var variable=$(this);
                var flag=$(this).prop('checked');
                var id=$(this).val();

                if(flag)
                 {

                    if(clear.attr("value")==variable.val())
                   {
                        var id=clear.attr("value");
                        var x=document.getElementById(id);
                        x.style.display="block";
                        clear.css('display','block');

                    }

                        }
                else  if(clear.attr("value")==variable.val())
                {   var id=clear.attr("value");
                    var x=document.getElementById(id);
                    x.style.display="none";
                    clear.css('display','none');

                }
                if(!numberOfChecked)
                {
                    var id=clear.attr("value");
                    var x=document.getElementById(id);
                    x.style.display="block";
                    clear.css('display','block');
                    }
             });    //clear
        });//all checkboxes
    }); //click  
         });//ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the following attribute to your checkboxs data-target='div#'
Then assign your divs ID the same value.

then with js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkboxs', function() {
var t = $(this).attr('data-target');
if(t != undefined) {
    //check if its already shown, if so hide!
    if($(this).attr('data-isshown')) {
        $("#"+t).hide();
        $(this).removeAttr('data-isshown')
    } else {
        $("#"+t).show();
        $(this).attr("data-isshown", true);
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: can you please elaborate it more?

Comment: interesting again it is not working with clear fix it is just working with the titles

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if I misunderstood your question, but you can accomplish this with CSS alone using the general sibling combinator:

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="box_a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="box_b" />

<div class="box" id="a">This is a box.</div>
<div class="box" id="b">This is b box.</div>
```

```css
.box {
    display: none;
}

.box_a:checked ~ #a,
.box_b:checked ~ #b {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dXKLL/

If you're not able to control the id values, you could base the connection on `nth-of-type`:

```css
.check:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .box:nth-of-type(1),
.check:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .box:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dXKLL/1/

If you need everything to be visible when no checkboxes are checked, you could use both the next sibling selector along with the general sibling selector:

```css
.check:not(:checked) + .check:not(:checked) ~ .box {
    display: block;
}
```

This will show all `.box` elements that follow at least two unchecked `.check` elements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dXKLL/2/

Comment: ty,the page should have all items and then if user tries to use checkboxes show them all

Comment: @Nickparsa Not sure I understand.

Comment: I have products for example x,y,z and they have classes yes? but the clearfix class is for all the products so I should recognize the difference with id and other things so I cannot use simply a class name